# Ассемблер. Арифметика

Tags: c++, ассемблер

Найти целочисленное решение уравнения `a*x+b=0`, если оно существует. Вопрос: как разделить -b на a

Comment: А в чем собственно состоит вопрос ? что вы уже пробовали сделать для его решения ?

Comment: легко получить -b, а после делить -b на а не получается

Comment: http://sadda.ru/pages/assembler-masm32/div/div.htm

Comment: Спасибо огромное